# Is there any better way of organising details in page

Tags: gui-design, organization

Please have a look at screen shot attached. Is there any way to organise the details.

[image]

I am not a designer but tried with following but looks clumsy

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Your second effort is on the right track. What's important in real estate leads? Mainly the contact information which should be at the top followed by their "Guest Desires"...price range/move-in date/other must haves/etc.

Consider tabs for stashing "Additional Details" or other data not critical for the sale process.